# Swipe left to delete cell does not work properly in ios 8 but works in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

The swipe to delete a table cell does not work properly. I have to swipe really fast and multiple times for it to work. The below code works in ios 7. Can someone tell me what I would need to do to get this to work smoothly in ios 8?

@implementation SimpleTableCell

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

-(void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state{

    [super willTransitionToState:state];


    if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]) {
                UIImageView *deleteBtn = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 33)];
                [deleteBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deleteButton.png"]];
                [[subview.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:deleteBtn];
            }
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue. After a few hours, I finally figured that the problem was coming from my navigation controller containing a swipe gesture recognizer.

The native comment editing feature uses a Swipe GestureRecognizer, so if you have any gesture recognizer, don't forget to add this line in order to allow simultaneous gesture recognition !!

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer { return YES; }
```

I really hope that it will help, because it was driving me crazy...

Answer (score 0):

This should be very straightforward  (and works fine for me, in iOS 8...)

You just need to make sure your UITableView has this:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // YES - we do want to enable "swipe to delete" on this row. 
    return YES;
}
```

...and this...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //  Add some code to delete your row...
}
```

Do you have these two pieces in your code ?